# When column number cycles to first number alter column B with new id

Tags: excel

I have a list of numbers that I need to map across two columns. Column A has a list of numbers that repeat every 1400 records, eg.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 |  | 12 |
| 12 |  | 428 |
| 12 |  | 6 |
| 12 |  |  |
| 12 |  |  |
| 14 |  |  |
| 14 |  |  |
| 14 |  |  |
| 14 |  |  |
| 12 |  |  |
| 12 |  |  |
| 12 |  |  |
| 12 |  |  |
| 12 |  |  |
| 14 |  |  |
| 14 |  |  |
| 14 |  |  |

I need to auto fill column B based on column C's data.

Column B should look like:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 12 | 12 |
| 12 | 12 | 428 |
| 12 | 12 | 6 |
| 12 | 12 |  |
| 12 | 12 |  |
| 14 | 12 |  |
| 14 | 12 |  |
| 14 | 12 |  |
| 14 | 12 |  |
| 12 | 428 |  |
| 12 | 428 |  |
| 12 | 428 |  |
| 12 | 428 |  |
| 12 | 428 |  |
| 14 | 428 |  |
| 14 | 428 |  |
| 14 | 428 |  |

Is there a formula that I can use to accomplish this? Column C has multiple records that I need to map to column A.
Every time Column A "REPEATS", in this case when 12 comes around again, I want column B to populate with the next number. In this case 428 then 6 ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of the repeated elements is always the same you can just divide the row number by that and index the elements in the C Column accordingly.

I.e. you have the sequence `12,12,12,12,12,14,14,14,14,14` which is of size 10. Then you can do this for the entries in column B:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(QUOTIENT(ROW()-ROW(B$1),N)+1,3))
```

Here `ROW()` is the row value of the cell. I supposed your numbers started from cell A1 and B1, otherwise you need to replace `ROW(B$1)` with the starting cell. The `$1` prevents the 1 to increment when you drag the list. Then, you take the quotient of that value with N, where N is the size of the sequence, in your case it is 10. The quotient gives you the integer part of the division. To that number you need to add 1, since excel starts indexing from 1 and not from 0. Then you need to find the reference for the right address of the values you want to put in column B, this is done with `ADDRESS(ROW_NUMBER,COLUMN_NUMBER)`, where `COLUMN_NUMBER` here is 3, since C is the third letter. (Change accordingly if you use a different column for the input) The `ROW_NUMBER` is the number we calculated. `INDIRECT(ADDRESS)` is a function that puts the value of the address that we got with the `ADDRESS` function.

This should work if your sequence of 12s and 14s is always of the same length. Otherwise, I suggest you leave excel and start using some programming language, such as python.